# nginx allow sub directory when location / is try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I have been trying to make this work but I am really out of options here :)

I am using CakePHP 3.0 with their suggested config plus making /tools/ (which contains phpmyadmin and so on) folder accessable without redirecting to index.php

```
server {
    listen       192.168.0.39:80;
    server_name  192.168.0.39;
    #root         www/webroot/;
    root         www/webroot/;
    index  index.php;

    log_not_found on;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    #the line I am trying to get to work.
    location /tools/ {
        root         www/;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9100;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000;
        #fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 100;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|swf|pdf|mp3|mp4|xml|txt|js|css)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    }

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){ return 405; }

    location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

I get no errors with this. But if I set root to a `notexisting` I get:

```
 "C:/server/notexisting/tools/index.php" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Otherwise it just shows 404.

access.log

```
192.168.0.39 - - [17/Jun/2015:17:35:27 +0300] "GET /tools/ HTTP/1.1" 404 191 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/30.0.1835.59" "-"
```

Tried playing around with `try_files` under location /tools/ but no luck.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why you want to set root to non-existing path?

Comment: I don't. I just did that for testing purposes to see an error because when I set root to www and I'm 100% sure it gives me 404 error and nothing in the log.